# Azure function error: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk, Version=7.0.0.0'?

Tags: azure, dynamics-crm, azure-functions, dynamics-crm-online

I m doing a azure function and testing it locally where it will add some data to Dyanmcis CRM. When I run function it throw this error:

**Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.**

Please note my code uses Microsoft.Xrm.Client(version 7) and it has Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk (version 8.1.0.235).

Please help.

Comment: Could you add a screenshot of expanded dependency tree from your Visual Studio solution explorer? My guess is that `7.0` is also a transient dependency somewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is due to the missing assembly redirect. You can see exactly which assembly redirect is needed by adding the `Microsoft.CrmSdk.CoreAssemblies` NuGet package to a normal .Net project and looking at the generated binding redirect statements added to `app.config`.

Currently Azure Functions do not support setting assembly redirects, so it has to be done in code. I solved this problem by using the code from this blog post: [How to fix the assembly binding redirect problem in Azure Functions](https://codopia.wordpress.com/2017/07/21/how-to-fix-the-assembly-binding-redirect-problem-in-azure-functions/)

With that code, `local.settings.json` looks like this:

```
"Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "",
    "AzureWebJobsDashboard": "",
    "BindingRedirects": "[ { \"ShortName\": \"Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk\", \"RedirectToVersion\": \"8.0.0.0\", \"PublicKeyToken\": \"31bf3856ad364e35\" } ]"
}
```

and in Application settings in the Azure portal:

```
[ { "ShortName": "Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk", "RedirectToVersion": "8.0.0.0", "PublicKeyToken": "31bf3856ad364e35" } ]
```