# How to load assembly file with SSIS C# scripting component to Azure Data Factory integrated runtime?

Tags: c#, azure, ssis, azure-data-factory

I have an SSIS package which contains a scripting component which extracts data from Dynamics 365. 
The package executes fine from Visual Studio and also from a local SQL server which I deployed it to to test.

I want to run the package from the cloud so I have setup an Azure integrated runtime to run the SSIS package using a pipeline, however when I try to execute the package from within Azure (using SSMS) I get a file not found error as below:

```
Dynamics Extract to Staging:Error: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could 
Not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk, Version=9.0.0.0, 
Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its 
dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

I assume this is related to the assembly file not being loaded to Azure along with the package, although I would have thought it was included as part of the SSIS package given the package executes fine when run from the local SQL Server i tested on?

I have read through [this](https://alisharifiblog.wordpress.com/2015/06/19/add-dll-to-gac-for-microsoft-dynamics-crm-ssis-packages/) and a few others describing the issue but most seem to be related to adding the assembly to a local server environment.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49021176/azure-function-error-could-not-load-file-or-assembly-microsoft-xrm-sdk-versio) also seems to refer to the same issue but is for functions and Im not sure how to apply this to my problem with executing the SSIS package in Azure data factory.

How do I ensure this assembly file is correctly deployed with the SSIS package to the Azure SSIS catalogue?

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I've been digging a bit further and found you need to install the assembly files to the integrated runtime node when it is first being spun up, this link from [microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/how-to-configure-azure-ssis-ir-custom-setup) didn't make much sense to me when i first read it but after reading this better explained example on [mssqltips](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5743/customized-setup-for-the-azuressis-integration-runtime/) and going back to it it reads a bit better.

I am in the process of running up the IR again at the moment so will see if this is indeed the solution i was looking for soon, thought id add this extra research to keep it all centralised.

EDIT: Yes, this was what i needed to do the package is now running correctly in the Azure IR, if your having this problem follow the steps in the two links above :)

Comment: Hey AJ ... do you have the installation files? I have been trying to find someting like .msi or .exe and I could find anything ... I have the same problem